# HTM5 draw a shape from multiple objects and then fill it and set opacity

Tags: html

For example lets say I am drawing some circle with arrow, transformatting it and rotating (code and jsfiddle below)... In given code, arrow is red... but when I make it gradient, the gradient is being rotaded during creation of whole object... so I need to apply gradient after everything is drawn... how do I do that?

Second thing... when applying global alpha opacity to context before drawing, arrow on circle is darker, because there are 2 layers in same place... how do I apply opacity to whole shape?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ND4Nz/)

```
var x1 = 10;
var y1 = 10;
var x2 = 50;
var y2 = 50;

var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;
var radians = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
var length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x1, y1);
ctx.rotate(radians);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red"; 
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(length, 0);
ctx.lineTo(length - 7, -4);
ctx.lineTo(length - 7, 4);
ctx.lineTo(length, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Gradient rotation**

When you createLinearGradient you specify the starting and ending xy's

(basically you specify the line along which the gradient will follow).

Therefore, you can adjust the angle of that line such that the gradient fits your design needs even after it's rotated.

**Opacity of the combined circle+arrow**

As you've discovered, if you overlap drawings then the resulting opacity will be darker on the overlap.

You have 2 solutions to the darkened opacity:

- start drawing the arrow at on the circumference of the circle rather than staring the arrow at the circle's center.  This way you have small or no overlap.
- combine the arc and arrow into 1 single path.